# How to set local storage limit in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

Is there a function that allows the user to nominate a set limit on how much storage is used locally on a phone or tablet?

For example, set Google Photos to only use 3GB of space on a phone. When locally stored, photos exceed that limit the oldest photos are deleted from the device but retained in the online Google Photos.

Comment: Can check the [storage limit](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/6558?hl=en) but limiting i am not sure.